# send api call before refreshing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have this piece of code somewhere in my app

```js
axios.post('url', {id:123});

window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?lang=' + this.language;
```

Problem is, request gets cancelled, probably maybe because refresh happens immediatelly..

I tried:

```js
window.addEventListener('unload', (event) =>  {
   axios.post('url', {id:123});
});
window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?lang=' + this.language;
```

This didn't help. Still gets cancelled.

What's the solution so that api request gets sent before refreshing ? i don't want to use setTimeout because I can't wait more than even 1 second for refresh to take place.

Comment: are you using vue router?

Comment: axios returns promise... why won't you use that callback to redirect ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes..

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  The `axios.post()` is asynchonous, so the page is redirected before the post completes.  Try something like this:

```
axios.post('/api/persons/unique/alias', {
        params: {
            id:123
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?lang=' + this.language;
    });
```

Comment: in this case, i have to wait for the request to end which might take sometimes 1-2 seconds which means refresh won't happen until that. That's something I can't take..